# LINQ class datasource not hard coded

Tags: linq, web-config

Does somebody know if it is possible to specify the data source of a LINQ class in a .dbml file to be read from the web.config file and not to be hard coded? I need it for the testing/production deployment changes.

Comment: What datasource? Do you mean connection string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager
    .ConnectionStrings["EnterpriseDb"]
    .ConnectionString;
return new EnterpriseDataContext(connectionString);
```

Got this from this forum post:

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/01273824-6eb6-4529-acd5-5154507afa55/

If that doesn't work for you, you try replacing the constructor for your context:

```
public class EnterpriseDataContext
{
    public EnterpriseDataContext() : base(
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EnterpriseDb"].ConnectionString)
    {
        OnCreated();
    }
}
```

Got that idea from:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jongallant/archive/2007/11/25/linq-and-web-application-connection-strings.aspx